Rails Many-to-Many Association: Unique Email Per Organization Is Being Enforced but same email that belongs to different org is not enforded
Here I have created many to many association between users and organizations through memberships and It is working fine but What I want is I want the same user(i.e user with same email) to be inserted into the users table if they belongs to different organization.
Here devise is checking the unique email validation in users and did not allow same duplicate users but I want to save it if it belongs to different organization.
Is is a valid approach? Is there any other alternatives solution?
# app/models/user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :organizations, through: :memberships
end

# app/models/organization.rb
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
end

# app/models/membership.rb
class OrganizationUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization

end

# app/db/migrate/20240810134227_devise_create_users.rb

class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :fullname
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      # t.integer :organization_id
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      # t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      # t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      # t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      # t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      # t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    # add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    # add_index :users, [:email, :organization_id], unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end


You don't need to create one more instance of User for this
Rename your model
app/models/membership.rb
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
end

Add unique index for membership
class AddIndexForUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  disable_ddl_transaction!

  def change
    add_index :memberships, [:user_id, :organization_id], algorithm: :concurrently, unique: true
  end
end

And then create membership instances for any user in organization
Membership.create(user: user, organization: organization)

